# Comment_form and GD Star Rating

Tags: comment-form, plugin-gd-star-rating

I'm finding GD Star Ratings a bit complex to work with. I'm using the comment_form function to generate a custom "review" form on a custom post type. At the top of the form, I want reviewers to leave their rating.

I am *guessing* that I want to hook into the "comment_form_top" action with one of the gd star ratings functions. Am I thinking the right direction? If so, do any of you have a code sample I could refer to? I'm having a hard time finding much in terms of documentation.

Any ideas and suggestions are welcomed - Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! The key was a custom callback on wp_list_comments. Here's the snippet of code I used within my comments:

```
    <?php if (defined("STARRATING_INSTALLED")) : ?>
        <div class="rating" style="float: right">
            <?php wp_gdsr_comment_integrate_standard_result(get_comment_ID()); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```